# Bootstrap causing unknown margin

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Please, I need help right here, I'm styling this booking form to make it fit with my layout and facing some quirky bugs that I don't know how to fix.

When I inspect the submit button there's a right margin which I don't know how to git rid of and what causes it? I'm kinda sure about the problem source which is a bootstrap grid but I tried everything I could think of to no effect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2dedfa30a2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="booking">
        <div class="service-box">
          <button><i class="fas fa-plane-departure"></i>Tours</button>
          <button><i class="fas fa-car"></i>Rent a car</button>
        </div>
        <div class="booking-form">
          <form>
            <div class="row justify-content-center no-margin">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-header">
                  <span>Find Your</span><br>
                  <b>Destination</b>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="row no-margin">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <span class="form-label">Where to</span>
                      <input class="form-control" list="browsers" name="myBrowser" placeholder="Ener a country">
<datalist class="form-control" id="browsers">

      <option value="Spain">

      <option value="France">

      <option value="Italy">

      <option value="United State">
</datalist>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <span class="form-label">From</span>
                      <input class="form-control" type="date">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <span class="form-label">From</span>
                      <input class="form-control" type="date">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-btn">
                  <button class="submit-btn"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>

    header {
        height: 130vh;
        background-image: url('../assets/134.jpg');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-position: center center;
    }

    .nav-bar {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        justify-items: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }

    .contact {
        justify-self: start;
        color: #fff;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }

    .nav-bar i {
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

    .contact a:hover {
        color: inherit
    }

    .tools {
        justify-self: end;
        color: #fff;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        justify-items: center;
    }

    .tools select {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .tools select option {
        background: rgba(226, 240, 251, 0.3);
        color: #ccc;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .navigation {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .navigation ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .navigation ul li:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: 15px
    }

    .navigation ul li:last-child i {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: darkgray
    }

    .navigation ul:last-child {
        position: relative;
    }

    .navigation ul li:last-child::after {
        content: '';
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: rgba(130, 141, 150, 0.3);
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 50%;
        right: 21px;
        bottom: -10px
    }

    .navigation ul li a:hover {
        color: inherit;
    }

    .text-logo {
        font-family: 'Courgette', serif;
        font-size: 80px;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(200px);
        transform: translateY(200px);
        margin: auto;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }



    #booking {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
        transform: translateY(230%);
    }

    .service-box {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: start;
        -ms-flex-pack: start;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .service-box button {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #fff;
        height: 50px;
        padding: 10px;
        color: #149A99;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        border: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        font-size: 16px;
        width: 200px
    }

    .service-box button i {
        margin: 10px;
        font-size: 18px
    }

    .service-box button:hover {
        background-color: #149A99;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .booking-form {
        background: #fff;
    }

    .booking-form > form .row.no-margin {
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }

    .booking-form > form .row.no-margin > [class*="col-"] {
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }

    .booking-form .form-header {
        line-height: 38px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #586458;
    }

    .form-header span {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #818390;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    .booking-form .form-header b {
        font-weight: 800;
        font-size: 18px;
    }


    .booking-form .form-group {
        position: relative;
        height: 110px;
        padding: 15px 10px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .booking-form .form-control {
        background-color: transparent;
        border-radius: 0px;
        border: none;
        height: 50px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #3c404a;
    }

    .booking-form select.form-control {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
    }

    .booking-form select.form-control + .select-arrow {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 20px;
        width: 32px;
        line-height: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        text-align: center;
        pointer-events: none;
        color: #818390;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .booking-form select.form-control + .select-arrow:after {
        content: '\279C';
        display: block;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }

    .booking-form .form-label {
        color: #818390;
        display: block;
        font-weight: 400;
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 600
    }

    .booking-form .submit-btn {
        background: #149A99;
        color: #fff;
        border: none;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 14px;
        display: block;
        height: 100px;
        width: 70px;
    }

    [type="date"] {
        background: #fff url(https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/calendar_2.png) 95% 50% no-repeat;
    }

    [type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
        display: none;
    }

    [type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    input {
        font-family: 'Pro Sans', sans-serif;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 3px 5px;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space is there because you put the submit button in a parent with a specific width. Specifically `col-md-2` (If a screen is 12 columns wide, this element is always 2 columns wide). Try removing that fixed column width and setting the parent to float right with `justify-content-end`.

```
<div class="row justify-content-end no-margin">
    ...
    <div class="">
        <div class="form-btn">
            <button class="submit-btn"><i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Full version working on JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6wk7bm40/

Comment: Could you please tell me why this is happening ? and the solution your provide is it the best practice to solve the problem ?

Comment: I think part of the problem is that Bootstrap is using FlexBox (col-md-2 is Bootstrap doing flexbox for you) and your custom CSS code is using Grid. If you're using col in Bootstrap, I recommend sticking to Flexbox for your custom CSS if possible. In terms of best practices for layout, I don't know, it depends how you want your elements spaced. If you want them to float to the right, use `justify-content-end`, if you want them evenly spaced, use `justify-content-around` or `justify-content-between`. If all the different Flexbox properties are confusing, check out https://flexboxfroggy.com/

Comment: This was useful, Thank you.